# How to get client IP in mimtproxy upstream mode

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, mitmproxy

It seems that client IP should be inside `client.peername` when intercepting `def client_connected(self, client):` inside your addon. Or same `flow.client_conn.peername` in `def http_connect(self, flow: mitmproxy.http.HTTPFlow)`

But I get there some internal IPs from my private network when running server on AWS. Same when exposing local port with ngrok.

I have my mitmproxy server running in Kubernetes cluster.

Traffic chain may be described the following way:

```
Elastic Load Balancer (classic/TCP mode) -> mitmproxy -> Upstream proxy
```

I tried to configure Load Balancer to support "Proxy protocol header" - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/enable-proxy-protocol.html

But mitmproxy does not seem to support "PROXY protocol: - https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/issues/4776

My mirmproxy addon (nothing special, just read varaible):

```
import mitmproxy.http
import mitmproxy.connection
import mitmproxy.proxy.server_hooks


class TestMetaAddon:
    def client_connected(self, client: mitmproxy.connection.Client, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f"client_connected: {client.__dict__}")
        print(f"Client IP: {client.peername}")

    def server_connect(self, data: mitmproxy.proxy.server_hooks.ServerConnectionHookData, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f"server_connect: {data.__dict__}")
        return

    def requestheaders(self, flow: mitmproxy.http.HTTPFlow):
        print(f"requestheaders: {flow.__dict__}")
        x_requested_for = flow.request.headers.get("X-Forwarded-For") or flow.request.headers.get("x-forwarded-for")
        print(f"requestheaders() - X-Forwarded-For: {x_requested_for}")
        print(f"requestheaders() - all headers: {flow.request.headers}")

addons = [TestMetaAddon()]
```

Comment: Sorry but your description is way too short to understand what you are talking about. Also please include existing (plugin) code.